# When to use container.setStartConsumerMinInterval(3000) rabbit mq spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, amqp, spring-amqp

I am new to spring boot amqp library,While I am searching for a solution I cam across this property .Can any one explain whats the use of this property

````
                .createListenerContainer();
container.setStartConsumerMinInterval(3000); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

See the documnentation

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#startConsumerMinInterval

> The time in milliseconds that must elapse before each new consumer is started on demand. See Listener Concurrency. Default: 10000 (10 seconds).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#listener-concurrency

> By default, the listener container starts a single consumer that receives messages from the queues.

> When examining the table in the previous section, you can see a number of properties and attributes that control concurrency. The simplest is `concurrentConsumers`, which creates that (fixed) number of consumers that concurrently process messages.

> ...

> In addition, a new property called `maxConcurrentConsumers` has been added and the container dynamically adjusts the concurrency based on workload. This works in conjunction with four additional properties: `consecutiveActiveTrigger`, `startConsumerMinInterval`, `consecutiveIdleTrigger`, and `stopConsumerMinInterval`.